# DB2 creating event monitor

Tags: database, db2

I'd like to create event monitor on DB2 z/OS 9.2 
i have spent a lot of time trying resolve this problem.

So i suggest this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0303kolluru/0303kolluru.html

and trying to make this steps:

```
db2 => connect to dbname user username using password 
db2 => update monitor switches using statement on 
db2 => create event monitor rkmon for statements write to file '/tmp' 
db2 => set event monitor rkmon state=1
```

but when I put command: create event monitor rkmon for statements write to file '/tmp' 
Db2 throw me an error:

```
"DB2ADMIN" does not have the privilege to perform operation "CREATE EVENT MONITOR".. SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, DRIVER=3.58.81
```

so, then i try add some privilege to my db2admin user:

```
grant DBADM to db2admin
```

but get another error:

```
The name "DBADM" cannot be used because the specified identifier is reserved for system use.. SQLCODE=-707, SQLSTATE=42939, DRIVER=3.58.81
```

Now, I don't have any idea what shoould i do to resolve this problem.

Maybe, there is some othere way to logs sql queries sends to my db2 ?

(I develop some java apps using hibernate and db2, and sometimes quickest way to resolve some problem is see what sql queries is send to db).

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the "ON DATABASE" clause is mandatory in the GRANT statement. Try:

```
grant DBADM on database to user db2admin
```

- [GRANT (database authorities)
  statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000958.html)

Comment: Good tip.

I open command line and without connect to db trying grant privileges:

Comment: But I got this error: 

`A database connection does not exist.`

and this is logical, so I connect to my database with:

`connect to mydatabase user db2admin password xxx`

and then try grant, but db2 error is: 

`DB2ADMIN.MYDATABASE is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704`

And this is also logical, i connected to database and be inside, therefore my database doesn't see this path.

I have only one user, created when installed my db2. 

 Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Oops, I gave the LUW syntax. The DB2 for z/OS syntax is different. Try    GRANT DBADM ON DATABASE mydatabase TO db2admin     . http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_sql_grantdatabaseprivileges.htm